# Display of DELL Optiplex 9010 all-in-one shaking on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, dell, screen

I am using a **DELL Optiplex 9010 all-in-one** machine for a long time with Ubuntu without having any issues. After having some updates, I did not restart the machine for 3-4 days. When I finally restart the machine the display starts shaking. I thought it may be an update issue. So I did update again (a few days later) with **sudo apt-get update** and **sudo apt-get upgrade**. Restarted the machine. But the problem is still there. Here I am attaching some pictures of the display taken by mobile phone.

1. When booting the Dell logo is fine. So I think the issue is not with the monitor.

[image: screenshot 1]

2. When the ubuntu logo appears it starts shaking:

[image: screenshot 2]

3. Finally os loaded and continue shaking, please see the date and time at the top:

[image: screenshot 3]

How can I fix it without reinstalling the OS?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

**UPDATE:** I have tested by connecting an external monitor. The external monitor display was fine. So Optiplex display went bad.

Comment: No need to reinstall. You can and should test it in a live session. If the problem persists then it's hardware. I strongly suspect it is considering that it has only and Intel integrated graphics that usually just works.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thanks for your comment. Yes, it does not have any external GPU. Any suggestion on how could I try to fix it?

Comment: If it's an hardware problem I'm afraid there's no fix other than replacing the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Change the default in the linux grub file as follows
for a Dell 9010 AIO:

```
grub_cmdline_linux_default= "quiet splash nomodeset acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=Dell"
```

works for me on Zorin.
Still can't modify the brightness though.